# Get AddressPO from an AddressBo object

Tags: intershop

I have an instance of an `AddressBO` in my code and i want to get corresponding `AddressPO` without using the `AddressPOFactory`. Is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java code try following:

```
addressBO.getExtension(PersistentObjectBOExtension.class).getPersistentObject()
```

In pipeline/ISML:

```
AddressBO:Extension("PersistentObjectBOExtension"):PersistentObject
```

Comment: The pipeline/ISML part of your answer only works if key `AddressBO` exists and denotes a value of `com.intershop.component.address.capi.AddressBO`. Just to set copy-paste expectations here.